# What is wrong with SOQL Condition Expression Syntax (WHERE Clause)

Tags: apex, soql

**1)  Working:**

```
SELECT CreatedDate, Account.CreatedDate FROM Opportunity
WHERE CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate) = 2016
```

**2)  Working:**

```
SELECT CreatedDate, Account.CreatedDate FROM Opportunity
WHERE CALENDAR_YEAR(Account.CreatedDate) = 2016
```

Above two SOQL are working in developer console. But SOQL below is not working. I want to know why SOQL WHERE clause behave like this OR there are any syntax error in my SOQL

**3)  Unknown error parsing query**

```
SELECT CreatedDate, Account.CreatedDate FROM Opportunity
WHERE CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate) = CALENDAR_YEAR(Account.CreatedDate)
```

**4)  Unknown error parsing query**

```
SELECT CreatedDate, Account.CreatedDate FROM Opportunity
WHERE CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate) = : CALENDAR_YEAR(Account.CreatedDate)
```

Comment: I suspect it is because the CreatedDate in the first query is not explicitly from either Account or Opportunity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each element of the [where clause](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_conditionexpression.htm) is limited to being only a [fieldExpression](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fieldexpression.htm):

> fieldName comparisonOperator value

where the value cannot be a reference to another field.